# Input value formatted with decimals

Tags: javascript, forms, input

Hello good people on SO.

So I have an input field in an Loan Calculator. In here I want the input value the user puts in to format with decimals (To more easily distinguish between 100000 and 1000000 in example.)

I want to use JavaScript to do this "conversion" if i might call it that, and I found something in the MDN Docs about a object construtctor called "Intl.NumberFormat"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

And I pasted in the following in my own JS file as shown below:

```
// Changes Loan Amount input to decimal format

document.getElementById("amount").addEventListener("input", function(){
 new Intl.NumberFormat('en-CA', {style: "decimal"}).format(amount);
});
```

My HTML Looks like this:

```html
<span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="amount"
                    placeholder="Loan Amount"
                  />
```

So the results I'm looking for Is to have the input look like when a user is typing is this:

[image: Wanted_Results]

Instead of this:

[image]

Hope this was clear. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: are you using any kind of framework like Angular or React? They would have different ways of doing this than if you're just using vanilla JavaScript. Also, you can check out [this CSS Tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/)

Comment: @Scrimothy , as of now I'm not using any frameworks. So I would like to be able to do it in vanilla javascript as I'm trying to learn the basics before I move on to frameworks. I will check out the link tho, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're not updating the input field with the formatted text:

```
document.getElementById("amount").addEventListener("input", function(){
    document.getElementById("amount").value = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-CA', {style: "decimal"}).format(document.getElementById("amount").value);
});
```

But, I think you'll want to strip non-numeric characters from each input iteration, so this might be closer to what you want:

```
document.getElementById("amount").addEventListener("input", function(){
    document.getElementById("amount").value = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-CA', {style: "decimal"}).format(document.getElementById("amount").value.match(/\d+/g).join(''));
});
```

Comment: I tried implementing what you wrote, but now my input field resets when it hits 3 or more numbers in the input field.

I get an error in the console, see the picture on the link below. 

https://gyazo.com/36cbdfead4c3ead76462dc64d0d01afb

My code now looks like this, see link below:
https://gyazo.com/a52b39666d176b7541d0a6ef813ab5c2?token=10a4abd3b61c3c9cc504b1e3d4751ef8

Comment: Did you use the second block?  That should strip non-numeric using Regex.

Comment: Hi, yes I tried that aswell. It didn't help either. I get the same error as posted previous comment.

Comment: .match returns an array, so you need to join it back into a string.  I edited the second code block above.

Comment: Thank you again for your comment.

However, I get the same error with the code you posted most recentyl in the second block. Please see my screenshot in the link below. Now, based on my lack of knowledge on RegEx, is it the ".value.match" property that isn't correct perhaps? Thank you again for your help.

SS of alert message: 
https://gyazo.com/256a09652ed5e8b42be37ca4bc447f3e

Comment: The second block works, I've tested it in FireFox, Chrome, IE, and Edge.  Do you have a typo?